# Criar uma coluna preenchida com 0 ou 1 baseada em outras colunas no Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-manipulation

Eu tenho um data frame e preciso preencher uma coluna com 0 ou 1 baseado no valores de outras 29 colunas. Se tiver 1 em qualquer uma das colunas de 0 a 28 a coluna com `Dor_leve` recebe 1, caso contrário recebe 0, para a coluna `Dor_media` é se tiver 2 em qualquer uma das colunas de 0 a 28 e para `Dor_grave` se tiver o valor 3 em qualquer coluna de 0 a 28.

Eu tenho as colunas `Col_0` a `Col_28` e necessito gerar as colunas `Dor_leve`, `Dor_media` e `Dor_grave` como abaixo. Os valores contidos nas colunas `Col_0` ... `Col_28` são 0 ou 1 ou 2
ou 3.

Exemplo do que necessito fazer:

```
Col_0 Col_1 Col_2 ... Col_28 Dor_leve Dor_media Dor_grave
0      1     1    ...   0         1         0        0
1      0     2    ...   0         1         1        0  
1      0     3    ...   1         1         0        1
2      3     0    ...   0         0         1        1 
0      0     0    ...   0         0         0        0
3      0     0    ...   1         1         0        1
```

As colunas são diferentes partes do corpo, então a pessoa pode ter 1, 2 ou 3 em cada coluna ou 0 em todas.
Tentativa foi:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('arquivo.xlsx', sheet_name=0, header=0)

# Crio as colunas com 0 para todos

df['Dor_leve']= 0
df['Dor_media']= 0
df['Dor_grave']= 0

# Atualizar os valores, com 1 para sim, se tem o problema

for index, value in df.items():
    if(value==1):
        df.loc[index,'Dor_leve']=1
    elif(value==2):
        df.loc[index, 'Dor_media']=1
    elif(value==3):
        df.loc[index, 'Dor_grave']=1
    insira o código aqui
```

Retornou esse erro:

```
> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty,
> a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Tentei:

```
if(df.items()==1):
   df['Dor_leve']=1

if(df.items()==2):
   df['Dor_media']=1
    
if(df.items()==3):
  df['Dor_grave']=1
```

Também não deu certo. Com o `if (df.items()==valor)` as colunas ficaram somente com valor 0.

Comment: Na ultima linha da tabela `3      0     0          1         1         0        0` a coluna `Dor_grave` não deveria ter o valor 1.

Comment: Deveria sim, erro meu ao digitar. Obrigado pela observação.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Primeiro estabeleça as colunas que você quer usar para checar a condição:

```
# definindo colunas manualmente
cols = ['Col_0', 'Col_1', 'Col_2', ...]  # preencha com as colunas aqui

# ou então usando uma compreensão de lista, dada uma lógica no nome das colunas
cols = [f'Col_{x}' for x in range(29)]
```

Depois, "pergunte" para cada linha das colunas de interesse se há a presença de `1`, `2`, ou `3`. O resultado dessa pergunta (`True`/`False`) é convertido no número inteiro `1` ou `0`. Podemos fazer essa pergunta usando `df.apply` e aplicando uma função à cada linha (com o argumento `axis=1`):

```
df['Dor_leve'] = df[cols].apply(lambda row: int(1 in row.values), axis=1)
df['Dor_media'] = df[cols].apply(lambda row: int(2 in row.values), axis=1)
df['Dor_grave'] = df[cols].apply(lambda row: int(3 in row.values), axis=1)
```

Comment: Diria que podes saltar o passo em que declaras/usas as `cols`: podia ficar só: `df.apply(lambda row: int(1 in row.values), axis=1)`. E se quiseres retirar as colunas "dor_..." podes só: `df.apply(lambda row: int(1 in row.values[:-3]), axis=1)`

Comment: Completei o comentário a pensar exatamente nisso d:

Comment: Muito obrigado pela grande ajuda. Não posso usar df.apply que na verdade o banco de dados possui outras colunas com valores de 0 ou 1 que são usados para outras classificações. Ah não ser que eu fizesse o slice do banco de dados e depois aplicar o df.apply no banco após o fatiamento. Grato pela atenção e ajuda de todos.